run nextjs 13 with react js version 17 is possible?
is it possible to run nextjs 13 with the react version 17,becasue when I upgraded my nextjs version to 13 it says that minimum react version requirement is 18, my codebase is not compatible with react 18, so..
I should be able to run nextjs 13 with react version 17

You can keep using react 17, but anytime in the future, it will be can cause many bugs. React 18 have more restricted and integration with server action that also used by nextjs 13.
Some solution you want to try:

Find alternative lib that support react 18
Rewrite so logic that make your unsupported lib workable on react 18 env
Keep the old version if it not a big deal


Downvoting because questions asked this badly should not be answered. Downvote, VTC, move on.
